# How to add new line between lines in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, files

I have a file `test.txt`. It has 120 lines in it. I want to add on line 70 a new line "test" so I get:

```
line 68
line 69
test
line 70
line 71
```

How can I do it in one line command without using text editors such as vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i '70i test' test.txt
```

is what you need to enter.